# Symfony 2 Doctrine: OrderBy - GroupBy Max Element with Joins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My problem is Doctrine and SQL GroupBy with Order By

So a little description there is a shop(s), the shop has articles(a) and there is an entity visit counter(vc) to count the visits of different things, also used for shop and article.

I want a list of articles(top articles), but just the most visited article for each shop.

```
   class Shop {
       private $id;
       private $name;
       private $is_published;
       ...
       /**
        * OneToMany articles
        */
       private $articles; 
   }

   class Article {
       private $id;
       private $name;
       private $is_published;
       ...
       /* ManyToOne Shop*/
       private $shop;
   }

   class VisitCounter {
       private $id;
       private $object_type; //0 for Article, 1 for Shop, 2 for Category
       private $object_id;
       ...
       private $nr_alltime_visits;
   }
```

Then I have tried with the following query in the article repository:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a', 's', 'vc')
            ->select('a, s')
            ->leftJoin('a.shop', 's')
            ->leftJoin('ProjMyBundle:VisitCounter', 'vc', 'WITH', 'vc.object_type = 0 AND cs.object_id= a.id')
            ->where('a.is_published = 1 AND s.is_published = 1)
            ->orderBy('vc.nr_alltime_visits', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('a.shop');
```

But for I didn't get the articles expected, if I remove the group by I get the right articles but more than 1 per Shop.

Any Ideas?

Before this problem I had a field in Shop and Article(private $nr_visits), and then I had something like this(could help someone in the future):

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a', 's')
                  ->select('a, s')
                  ->where('a.is_published = 1 AND s.is_published = 1')
                  ->leftJoin('a.shop', 's')
                  ->groupBy('a.shop')
                  ->orderBy('nr_visits', 'DESC');


    $query->andWhere('a.nr_visits = (SELECT MAX(a2.nr_visits) as nr_visits2 FROM ProjMyBundle:Article AS a2 WHERE a2.is_published = 1 AND a2.shop=a.shop GROUP BY a2.shop)');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible with a subquery like in the old version:

```
$qb->select('a, s, cs')->leftJoin('a.shop', 's')
        ->leftJoin('ProjMyBundle:VisitCounter', 'vc', 'WITH', 'vc.object_type = :object_type AND cs.object_id=a.id')
        ->where('a.published = 1 AND s.published = 1)
        ->andWhere('vc. nr_alltime_visits = (SELECT MAX(vc2.nr_alltime_visits) as hits2 FROM ProjMyBundle:Article AS a2
                            LEFT JOIN ProjMyBundle:VisitCounter AS vc2 WITH vc2.object_type = :object_type AND vc2.object_id = a2.id
                            WHERE a2.published = 1 v2.shop=v.shop GROUP BY v2.shop)')
        ->setParameters(array('object_type' => Clicks::$TYPE_ARTICLE))
        ->orderBy('cs.nr_alltime_visits', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('v.shop')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

VisitCounter does not have a direct relation to Shop or Article, because the object_id column is depended on object_type column. So then you can not use doctrine's fetch-joins because it expects a direct relationship to be there. You have to write some native SQL, but you can still use some doctrine goodies to help you make nice objects (though array's are prefered for read operations).

As for your query you need to look for "Top N by group" which is different on each database platform (which you didn't specify in your question). You have to Group By the article (and shop) and then do a COUNT(*) on the rows you aggregate.

Here you can read how to map the results from native sql: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples

Comment: thank you for your comment the problem was solved in then a new dql inside the query was done.
      $query->andWhere('cs.visits_all_time = ( /* new query*/